# Error 404 after install gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I've installed gitlab on centos 7. I've followed the instructions [gitlab instructions](https://about.gitlab.com/installation/#centos-7) ,  I 've set the external url as 192.168.0.6/gitlab but I got a 404 error when I browse this url. I've never installed Gitlab before but on apache document root there is no Gitlab folder. What can be wrong? Did I missed something?

Comment: Did you proceed to browse after succesfull installation or you browsed in middle?

Comment: afer,it's solved now